# What is the equivalent to moz-box-orient?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been looking around the internet and through a number of different reference lists, but can't find the "universal" equivalent to `-moz-box-orient`.

The problem I am currently met with is in reversing my boxes without reversing the entire placement.

This is what I want to achieve, that is, keeping all of the boxes to the left hand side through orientation:

```css
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-direction: reverse;
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-direction: reverse;
}
#parent > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 { background: green; }
#child2 { background: yellow; }
#child3 { background: red; }
#child4 { background: orange; }
```

```html
<section id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Child #1</div>
  <div id="child2">Child #2</div>
  <div id="child3">Child #3</div>
  <div id="child4">Child #4</div>
</section>
```

This is my attempt without `-moz-box-orient`:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
#parent > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 { background: green; }
#child2 { background: yellow; }
#child3 { background: red; }
#child4 { background: orange; }
```

```html
<section id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Child #1</div>
  <div id="child2">Child #2</div>
  <div id="child3">Child #3</div>
  <div id="child4">Child #4</div>
</section>
```

To surmise my question once more:
Does anyone know the equivalent to `-moz-box-orient: horizontal;`?

Comment: `-moz-box-orient` appeared in early drafts of the CSS flexible box layout specification, but it's now been removed. [Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient). You should stop using it and find another way.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was suspecting, but was rather hoping wasn't the case.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`box-orient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient) is a property of the original CSS Flexible Box Layout Module draft, and has been replaced in newer drafts.

A more or less equivalent is [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction), which you already use.

If you want to align the elements to the left, you can try [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

```css
justify-content: flex-end;
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#parent > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 { background: green; }
#child2 { background: yellow; }
#child3 { background: red; }
#child4 { background: orange; }
```

```html
<section id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Child #1</div>
  <div id="child2">Child #2</div>
  <div id="child3">Child #3</div>
  <div id="child4">Child #4</div>
</section>
```

However, note that with your old code, the reversed items are aligned to the right side too, but you don't see it because the container shrinks because of `display: -moz-box`.

If you want the same behavior, you can use `display: inline-flex`:

```css
#parent {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
#parent > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 { background: green; }
#child2 { background: yellow; }
#child3 { background: red; }
#child4 { background: orange; }
```

```html
<section id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Child #1</div>
  <div id="child2">Child #2</div>
  <div id="child3">Child #3</div>
  <div id="child4">Child #4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'll bear that in mind as a solution to the placement issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!